# App Widget Layout warning

Tags: android, layout, android-appwidget

[In develepoers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) it is advised to use the following layout for App Widgets.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/my_widget_background">

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Naturally Eclipse have the warning *This LinearLayout layout or its FrameLayout parent is useless*.
is it correct? Can I remove the LinearLayout?

Comment: parent layout always Linear or relative not use frame layout as a parent

Comment: @sunil, crbin1 just posted the recommended code in Developer's guide. There it says the recommended main layout for appwidgets is a padded FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what the content of your widget is. Do you need a LinearLayout or a FrameLayout to position your content correctly? From you question one can't answer that question. But if it's a LinearLayout then the following is identical to the layout above:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/my_widget_background">
</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that I added the layout_margin attribute instead of using the padding because the background will be drawn regardless of what padding you define.